# Transactions in a Foxpro & MYSQL Application

Tags: mysql, foxpro

With reference to This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms947432.aspx

Sample Code which I assume works since it is posted in Microsoft's site.

```
&& Start a VFP transaction and a transaction on the server.
Begin Transaction  && FoxPro Start Trans Command

=SQLExec(nConnection, 'BEGIN TRANSACTION')  && SQL Start Trans Commnad

&& Update changes to MyTable.    
lEverythingOK = TableUpdate( 2, .F., 'rv_MyView' )

If lEverythingOK
 && Update changes to MyOtherTable.
 lEverythingOK = tableupdate( 2,.F.,'rv_MyOtherView')
EndIf

&& End the transaction on the server and VFP.

If lEverythingOK
 =SQLExec(nConnection, 'COMMIT')   && SQL COMMIT COMMAND
 End Transaction                   && Foxpro COMMIT COMMAND 
Else
 =SQLExec( nConnection, 'ROLLBACK' )  && SQL ROLLBACK COMMAND
 RollBack                             && FoxPro ROLLBACK COMMAND
EndIf
```

This sample is based on MS SQL and Foxpro using Remote View. I wanted to recreate this using MYSQL and Foxpro using Remote View. The Problem is if I issue the command TableUpdate, the record gets committed to MYSQL server even if I have not yet issued the      =SQLExec( nConnection, 'COMMIT' ) command. Im using INNODB Engine. Pls Note that if I omit the TableUpdate command, I am able to COMMIT or ROLLBACK my transaction from MYSQL. I was hoping not to remove the command TableUpdate to trap errors in my record so that I wouldt have to check for errors record for record before commiting it to MYSQL server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't make any changes to FoxPro data so it doesn't need local transaction handling. If you've added this in not because you're doing local data updates within the same transaction but because you think it 'might help', take it out. That might fix the problem.

If you are making local changes within the same transaction anyway you want to reconsider that design anyway, as you should be doing local changes after the remote query is completed.

If that doesn't fix it, then your question says 'the record' gets committed, but you are updating two remote views in your example - does the code work with just one? If not, are both updated? What happens if you rollback the first? What about if you're working against a table instead of a view? Can the changes not be rolled back at all?

If you can come up with a minimal reproducible sample then your chances of getting an answer (or even a solution) are much higher.

Comment: I'd assume that the changes to the data occurred before the code we're seeing. There's no reason to start a transaction until you've made your changes and are ready to save.

Answer (score 0):

Try using autocommit:

> SET autocommit=0

From the MySQl documentation:

After disabling autocommit mode by setting the autocommit variable to zero, changes to transaction-safe tables (such as those for InnoDB, BDB, or NDBCLUSTER) are not made permanent immediately. You must use COMMIT to store your changes to disk or ROLLBACK to ignore the changes.